# Why do I have to press ENTER several times before receiving input from CreateProcess() child process using pipes?

Tags: c++, c, windows, process

Given the following program, where I create a `cmd.exe` child process, why do I've to press `ENTER` two times before I receive the command output (read from the standard output pipe) ?

My goal is to emulate a "true" `cmd.exe` experience. However, the extra `ENTER` clicks kinda ruins this feel, since you get two prompts before receiving the output (from the child process).

Also, I wonder, why doesn't a prompt gets displayed in the child process `cmd.exe` console window? It is just blank, but I see that it stills receives input, executes it, and sends back output.

Would be happy for an explanation of this problem.

Thanks...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSZ 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buf[BUFFSZ];

    STARTUPINFO si;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // Pipe handles
    HANDLE hChildStd_IN_Rd, hChildStd_OUT_Wr, hChildStd_OUT_Rd, hChildStd_IN_Wr;

    printf("Program started...\n");

    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));

    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);

    // Inheritable handles
    sa.bInheritHandle = true;

    // StdInput pipe
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_IN_Rd, &hChildStd_IN_Wr, &sa, 0))
    {
        printf("CreatePipe() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // StdOutput pipe
    if (!CreatePipe(&hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0))
    {
        printf("CreatePipe() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    GetStartupInfo(&si);

    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
    si.hStdOutput = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdError = hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdInput = hChildStd_IN_Rd;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Create child process
    if (!CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"), NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        printf("CreateProcess() failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned long exit; // Exit code
    unsigned long bread; // Bytes read
    unsigned long avail; // Bytes available

    ZeroMemory(buf, sizeof(buf));

    for (;;)
    {
        // Get termination status of child process
        if (!GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exit)) {
            printf("GetExitCodeProcess() failed\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (exit != STILL_ACTIVE) {
            break;
        }

        // Check to see if data available in pipe
        PeekNamedPipe(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buf, BUFFSZ, &bread, &avail, NULL);

        if (bread != 0)
        {
            ZeroMemory(buf, sizeof(buf));


            if (avail > BUFFSZ)
            {
                while (bread >= BUFFSZ)
                {
                    ReadFile(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buf, BUFFSZ, &bread, NULL); 
                    printf("%s", buf);
                    ZeroMemory(buf, sizeof(buf));
                }
            }
            else {
                // Read all data from StdOut pipe in one chunk
                ReadFile(hChildStd_OUT_Rd, buf, BUFFSZ, &bread, NULL);
                printf("%s", buf);
            }
        }
        if (_kbhit())      //check for user input.
        {
            ZeroMemory(buf, sizeof(buf));
            *buf = (char)getchar();
            WriteFile(hChildStd_IN_Wr, buf, 1, &bread, NULL); 

            if (*buf == '\r') {
                *buf = '\n';
                WriteFile(hChildStd_IN_Wr, buf, 1, &bread, NULL);                                               
            }
        }
    }

    // Clean up
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(hChildStd_IN_Rd);
    CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
    CloseHandle(hChildStd_OUT_Rd);
    CloseHandle(hChildStd_IN_Wr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I/O redirection falls flat on its face with  interactive programs like Cmd.exe.  Like any CRT-based program, it switches stdout to buffered mode when it detects that it is no longer sending output to a terminal.  Underlying call is isatty().  Matters a lot, buffered output is a lot faster.  That buffer doesn't get flushed until it fills to capacity or the stream is closed.  Pressing Enter several times puts enough bytes in the buffer to get it to flush.  Nothing you can do about that.  Google "getta byte, getta byte, getta byte byte byte".

Comment: @HansPassant can I somehow switch to unbuffered mode? What do you mean by "sending output to a terminal"? Pressen ENTER just put 2 bytes more in the buffer? Is it the child process that detects it is no longer sending this output? Thanks for the Google hint.